# AWS s3 mp4 not working in Chrome using CNAME

Tags: google-chrome, amazon-s3, mp4

I have a mp4 file hosted on S3 that works well in Firefox but not in Chrome. I have set a CNAME pointing to my S3 bucket. If I link directly using the original S3 object URL it works fine, even in Chrome. Also, if I link using my CNAME with SSL ON, although I have an Invalid Certificate Warning, if I accept it works.

One more thing, I have looked in Chrome developer tools, and it displays a 'Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type video/mp4: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/media.devmcgill.com/videos/projet/titrevideo2/low.mp4".', I thought that was the issue, but it is there on all URL I try, succesful or not.

Here are the URL I'm using

S3 Link (works) : https://s3.amazonaws.com/media.devmcgill.com/videos/projet/titrevideo2/low.mp4

CNAME link over SSL (works) : https://media.devmcgill.com/videos/projet/titrevideo2/low.mp4

CNAME (fails) : http://media.devmcgill.com/videos/projet/titrevideo2/low.mp4

I have set Content-Type Metadata to  "video/mp4" on my video in S3

Thanks for your help sorting out what's going on.

Comment: I am using chrome and clicking the cname link loads a html5 video player for me.

Comment: Well, I dont know why but it's working now.

Comment: We are intermittently seeing the same issue! Feels like it's related to some caching thing but no proof yet. Our exact error in the Chrome Console "Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type video/mp4" chrome"

Comment: We're also getting this issue, mp4 video would faststart and play perfectly over HTTPS, and same URL over HTTP would not faststart, and the download is interrupted (cancelled) just before it finishes.

Comment: If your url doesn't have file extension then chrome figures out automatically but still sometimes Download managers might be issue here.I disabled automatic downloading of files having url " s3.amazonaws.com" in Internet Download Manager. Now the browser starts online player and plays the video.

Comment: Thank you Amit, but I did have file extensions.